# Error <<Cannot read property 'parentNode' of null >> con Jquery DataTables

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, datatables

Estoy armando una tabla dinamicamente, esto lo he hecho en otros modulos de mi página exactamente igual, pero esta vez me está generando ese error y no sé a qué se debe, en la página tengo otra tabla que la armo casi de la misma forma, lo único que cambian son los datos y esta no me genera error, no sé que puede ser, les dejare un pantallazo para que vean que error me aparece:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como ve la tabla de arriba no toma el estilo y se daña, además que no toma el sorting, y es porque algo está mal en el código o no sé.

Ya revisé el código que uso pero no encuentro un error o algo :/

Miren, el código que uso es este, como dije, la armo dinamicamente, para eso recorro dos arrays y voy armando el HTML:

```js
function ArmarTabla() {
    $("#container_TGrid_Arrastre").html("");
    $("#container_TGrid_Arrastre").css("display", "none"); //Div que contiene tabla para arrastre

    var html_Arrastre = "";

    html_Arrastre = "<table id='T_Arrastre' border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' style='width: 100%'><thead> ";
    html_Arrastre = html_Arrastre + "<tr id='Arrastre_Cabecera_A'><th class='Grid_Head' rowspan='3'>Día</th><th class='Grid_Head' colspan='8'>Horario</th><th class='Grid_Head' rowspan='3'>Acción</th></tr> "; //Armamos las cabeceras fijas
    html_Arrastre = html_Arrastre + "<tr id='Arrastre_Cabecera_A_B'><th class='Grid_Head' colspan='2'>A</th><th class='Grid_Head' colspan='2'>B</th><th class='Grid_Head' colspan='2'>C</th><th class='Grid_Head' colspan='2'>D</th></tr> "
    html_Arrastre = html_Arrastre + "<tr id='Arrastre_Cabecera_B'><th class='Grid_Head'>Inicial</th><th class='Grid_Head'>Final</th><th class='Grid_Head'>Inicial</th><th class='Grid_Head'>Final</th><th class='Grid_Head'>Inicial</th><th class='Grid_Head'>Final</th><th class='Grid_Head'>Inicial</th><th class='Grid_Head'>Final</th></tr> "; //Armamos las cabeceras fijas
    html_Arrastre = html_Arrastre + "</thead><tbody> "

    for (var i in MatrizArrastre) {
        html_Arrastre = html_Arrastre + "<tr id='ArrastreDay_" + MatrizArrastre[i].DayName + "'>"; //ID del TR
        for (var j in ArrayDayWork) { //Recorremos el array que contiene los días laborales y los que no
            if (MatrizArrastre[i].Dia == ArrayDayWork[j][0]) {
                if (ArrayDayWork[j][2] == false) { //SI ese día no es laboral colocamos en ROJO
                    html_Arrastre = html_Arrastre + "<td><span class='cssToolTip_Form'><b style='color: #6B1010; cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;'>" + MatrizArrastre[i].DayName + "</b><span>Día no Laboral</span></span></td>"; //Armamos la identificación del Día
                    html_Arrastre = html_Arrastre + "<td> - </td><td> - </td><td> - </td><td> - </td><td> - </td><td> - </td><td> - </td><td> - </td><td> - </td></tr>"; //Colocamos los horarios
                    break;
                } else if (ArrayDayWork[j][2] == true) { //Si ese día si es laboral pintamos normal
                    html_Arrastre = html_Arrastre + "<td>" + MatrizArrastre[i].DayName + "</td>"; //Armamos la identificación del Día
                    html_Arrastre = html_Arrastre + "<td style='cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;'><span class='cssToolTip_Boton'>" + MatrizArrastre[i].A_HoraIni + "<span><input type='radio' class='Ver' name='option' style='cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;' onclick=\"EditHoraDia('" + MatrizArrastre[i].ID + "', 'A');\">Editar<br><input type='radio' class='Ver' name='option' style='cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;' onclick=\"DeleteHoraDia('" + MatrizArrastre[i].ID + "','A');\">Eliminar</span></span></td><td>" + MatrizArrastre[i].A_HoraFin + "</td><td style='cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;'><span class='cssToolTip_Boton'>" + MatrizArrastre[i].B_HoraIni + "<span><input type='radio' class='Ver' name='option' style='cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;' onclick=\"EditHoraDia('" + MatrizArrastre[i].ID + "', 'B');\">Editar<br><input type='radio' class='Ver' name='option' style='cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;' onclick=\"DeleteHoraDia('" + MatrizArrastre[i].ID + "','B');\">Eliminar</span></span></td><td>" + MatrizArrastre[i].B_HoraFin + "</td><td style='cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;'><span class='cssToolTip_Boton'>" + MatrizArrastre[i].C_HoraIni + "<span><input type='radio' class='Ver' name='option' style='cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;' onclick=\"EditHoraDia('" + MatrizArrastre[i].ID + "', 'C');\">Editar<br><input type='radio' class='Ver' name='option' style='cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;' onclick=\"DeleteHoraDia('" + MatrizArrastre[i].ID + "','C');\">Eliminar</span></span></td><td>" + MatrizArrastre[i].C_HoraFin + "</td><td style='cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;'><span class='cssToolTip_Boton'>" + MatrizArrastre[i].D_HoraIni + "<span><input type='radio' class='Ver' name='option' style='cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;' onclick=\"EditHoraDia('" + MatrizArrastre[i].ID + "', 'D');\">Editar<br><input type='radio' class='Ver' name='option' style='cursor: pointer; cursor: hand;' onclick=\"DeleteHoraDia('" + MatrizArrastre[i].ID + "','D');\">Eliminar</span></span></td><td>" + MatrizArrastre[i].D_HoraFin + "</td><td> - </td></tr>"; //Colocamos los horarios
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    html_Arrastre = html_Arrastre + "</tbody></table>";//Cerramos tabla principal

    $("#container_TGrid_Arrastre").html(html_Arrastre);  
    $("#container_TGrid_Arrastre").css("display", "inline-table"); //Div que contiene tabla para arrastre

    //$("#T_Arrastre").dataTable({
    //    "bJQueryUI": true,
    //    "iDisplayLength": 15,
    //    "bDestroy": true,
    //    "aoColumnDefs": [
    //      { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] }
    //    ]
    //});

    $("#T_Arrastre").dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true, "iDisplayLength": 1000,
        "bDestroy": true
    });
}
```

```html
<div id="container_TGrid_Arrastre" style="width: 900px; overflow: auto; border: solid 1px #CACACA; font: 12px/20px CenturyGothic,sans-serif; text-align: center; margin-top: 5px;">
            </div>
```

Verán que hay una línea comentada, eso es como se supone que debería armarse la tabla, así la deseo, pero no toma ningún estilo, y siempre arroja un error.

Las matrices que utilizo son estas:

```
//Matriz de arrastre
    var MatrizArrastre = [];
    MatrizArrastre[0] = {
        A_HoraFin: "0",
        A_HoraIni: "0",
        B_HoraFin: "0",
        B_HoraIni: "0",
        C_HoraFin: "0",
        C_HoraIni: "0",
        D_HoraFin: "0",
        D_HoraIni: "0",
        DayName: "Lunes",
        Dia: 1
    };
    MatrizArrastre[1] = {
        A_HoraFin: "0",
        A_HoraIni: "0",
        B_HoraFin: "0",
        B_HoraIni: "0",
        C_HoraFin: "0",
        C_HoraIni: "0",
        D_HoraFin: "0",
        D_HoraIni: "0",
        DayName: "Martes",
        Dia: 2
    };
    MatrizArrastre[2] = {
        A_HoraFin: "0",
        A_HoraIni: "0",
        B_HoraFin: "0",
        B_HoraIni: "0",
        C_HoraFin: "0",
        C_HoraIni: "0",
        D_HoraFin: "0",
        D_HoraIni: "0",
        DayName: "Miércoles",
        Dia: 3
    };
    MatrizArrastre[3] = {
        A_HoraFin: "0",
        A_HoraIni: "0",
        B_HoraFin: "0",
        B_HoraIni: "0",
        C_HoraFin: "0",
        C_HoraIni: "0",
        D_HoraFin: "0",
        D_HoraIni: "0",
        DayName: "Jueves",
        Dia: 4
    };
    MatrizArrastre[4] = {
        A_HoraFin: "0",
        A_HoraIni: "0",
        B_HoraFin: "0",
        B_HoraIni: "0",
        C_HoraFin: "0",
        C_HoraIni: "0",
        D_HoraFin: "0",
        D_HoraIni: "0",
        DayName: "Viernes",
        Dia: 5
    };
    MatrizArrastre[5] = {
        A_HoraFin: "0",
        A_HoraIni: "0",
        B_HoraFin: "0",
        B_HoraIni: "0",
        C_HoraFin: "0",
        C_HoraIni: "0",
        D_HoraFin: "0",
        D_HoraIni: "0",
        DayName: "Sábado",
        Dia: 6
    };
    MatrizArrastre[6] = {
        A_HoraFin: "0",
        A_HoraIni: "0",
        B_HoraFin: "0",
        B_HoraIni: "0",
        C_HoraFin: "0",
        C_HoraIni: "0",
        D_HoraFin: "0",
        D_HoraIni: "0",
        DayName: "Domingo",
        Dia: 7
    };
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré el problema, al parecer es una tontada, el ID de la tabla, y el ID de los TR no pueden llevar el guión bajo `_`, eso genera un error, solo lo cambie del código y se arregló

```
html_Arrastre = "<table id='TArrastre' border='1' cellpadding='1' cellspacing='1' style='width: 100%'><thead> ";

html_Arrastre = html_Arrastre + "<tr id='ArrastreDay" + MatrizArrastre[i].DayName + "'>"; //ID del TR
```

Y ya, al colocar el datable no genera error

```
$("#TArrastre").dataTable({
        "bJQueryUI": true,
        "iDisplayLength": 15,
        "bDestroy": true,
        "aoColumnDefs": [
          { 'bSortable': false, 'aTargets': [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] }
        ]
    });
```